# Two vertical section with bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

Ive been struggling for the past day on this issue, if someone can help me I would be thankful !
I am trying to do something like this with bootstrap 5.
[goal I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGWl9.png)

I know how to do the form, centre the logo and all, but I'm not able to split the page into two vertical section, I want to use bg-dark on the left and bg-secondary on the right.
Here's what I have for now:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 bg-dark p-0">
                <img src="/img/FOODIGO.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 bg-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente facere adipisci tempore perspiciatis aliquid nostrum impedit deserunt doloremque. Voluptatum ullam quo incidunt quae eligendi autem nesciunt dolore, asperiores suscipit quas.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick.

for more info you can read up here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_grid_basic.php

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="height:100vh;">
        <div class="col-sm-4 bg-dark p-0">
            <img src="/img/FOODIGO.svg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 bg-secondary" style="height:100vh;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente facere adipisci tempore perspiciatis aliquid nostrum impedit deserunt doloremque. Voluptatum ullam quo incidunt quae eligendi autem nesciunt dolore, asperiores suscipit quas.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have updated the answer to include your initial code. this will allow your section to also be responsive as well.

Basically by adding -fluid to your container we stretch the container 100% the width of the parent container.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, It does take the whole page in question of width but I need it to take the whole page in term of height too and I can't manage to do it:(
thank you for your answer !

Comment: just add height:100vh; to your css on a class for that row such as .row {height:100vh;}

Comment: updated answer and added it to the rows to give you a visual :) let me know if I can assist further.